# powershell enable-psremoting for remote machine

Tags: powershell

Enabling Ps-Remoting on a machine for which i have admin access from another machine threw this error 
`Access is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], In
   validOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQu
   ickConfigCommand`

Any Alternative way of enabling ps-remoting in a remote machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a job on the remote machine that runs a powershell script. In the script, run the Enable-PSRemoting cmdlet with the force switch. The process must be elevated.

Answer (score 0):

Within a domain I'm having good luck with [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

```
.\psexec \\servername -s -d powershell "Enable-PSRemoting -Force"
```

The -s runs the remote proecess in the System account.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my trouble shooting guide to fixing this problem, it covers:

- Is your machine connected to a domain or work group?
- Are you logged in as a local Administrator?
- Was PowerShell launched as 'Administrator'?
- Is your password blank?
- Are you trying to connect to a SharePoint farm?
- Is your Server hosted/managed by a Hosting company?
- Are you using VirtualBox?
- Are you running Windows XP?
- Are you running the command on a computer where the language is not
  set to English?

[https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied/568228#568228)